# Spring 3.x PropertyOverrideConfigurer insists on using set, not constructor

Tags: spring

Trying to use Spring PropertyOverrideConfigurer or some such subclass, to help
create the following bean:

```
public class Foo {
  private final String name;

  public Foo(String name) { this.name = name; }

  public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Suppose my bean definition is something like

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
  <constructor-arg name="name" value="abc">
</bean>
```

I've handed Spring a file foo.properties, in there it finds an entry
foo.name="def"

So the default name property for Foo bean is "abc", I want it overriden to be "def";
HOWEVER I do not want to have an explicit setName(String name) method hanging
off my Foo class, since despite what Spring thinks I consider this a terrible
idea in software development. I expect Spring to be able to pass the
overridden value as "def" to the constructor of Foo,
not call Foo later with setName("def").

I have not gotten this to work, is there a way? The only success I've had is
to add the method

```
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
```

to the Foo class, which again I think is a terrible idea since it opens
up your class for unintentional side-effecting later.

Is there any hope? Can I modify the bean definition somewhere before
Spring creates Foo with the (wrong) "abc" name?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544525/constructor-injection-with-value-provided-by-another-bean) you can find a solution. It works for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it. You xml should look somewhat like:

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="abc"/>
</bean>
```

Assuming that constructor has one parameter and "abc" is a value coming from your property file. In this case the setter is not needed.

More information is available in Spring documentation at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators

Comment: Sorry I mistyped my bean definition, I was already using constructor-arg not property, will fix my post.

Comment: Then your question makes no sense. If you have constructor-arg defined - parameters are passed into constructor on bean creation

Comment: "abc" gets passed in, not "def". Later Spring comes along and calls setName("def") which is not what I wanted. I want the constructor to be called with "def"