# constructor injection with value provided by another bean

Tags: spring

I want to pass value to constructor(type string) with value provided by another bean.

Class BeanOne () {
BeanOne (String message) {
...
}
}

***Below declaration will work***

```
<bean id="beanOne"
    class="com.abc.BeanOne">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String"
        value="Hi There" /> // instead of value="Hi There", i want to use bean property (value="someBean.message")
</bean>
```

However I want another bean (say BeanTwo) to set value for message property for BeanOne. I tried nested property as given below but it does not work. Also message property is not visible directly in the class & is referred internally by another constructor & then by the method so i cannot use property injection& have to use only constructor injection

Comment: BTW: You do not need to specifiy an index (and/or type) for an constructor if it can be assigned automatically by Spring. -- So for example if you have only one parameter, or all parameters are of different type, then you can omit the index attribute in you xml configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) to get your string value and then inject that into your bean.

```
         <bean id="message" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject"><ref local="someBean"></property>
            <property name="targetMethod"><value>getMessage</value></property>
         </bean>

         <bean id="beanOne"  class="com.abc.BeanOne">
            <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" ref="message"/>
         </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks "MethodInvokingFactoryBean" option worked. Hope i can be someday better as you and would have find it before asking :(